# npm publish : update a version without changing the latest

Tags: npm

I am working on two versions of the same package (v1 and v2; v2 being the `@latest`).
I did an hotfix today on the v1 and republish the package:

```
npm publish --registry https://...
```

It worked, the patch version of my v1 got incremented and published.
However, when I tried doing a `npm i ...@latest` after, I got that latest v1 version instead of the v2. How can I change the publish so he doesn't overwrite the `@latest` tag ?

Comment: Did you read https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-publish? `Sets tag 'latest' if no --tag specified`.

Comment: It appears that this information ^^ is correct - but you cannot use a "semver" for your tag (eg. `--tag=v1.x.x` is not valid), but you can use any arbitrary string instead (eg. `--tag=v1-latest`). The point is that setting a `--tag` while publishing tells npm not to re-assign the special "latest".

Comment: Cheers, yeah I read it, but I was confused with the string I had to use instead.